# Vendored assets in a Rails engine not loading when used as a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

Im writing an isolated Rails Engine which has it's own javascript in `app/assets` which in turn loads a bunch of dependencies that are kept in the engine's `vendor/assets`.

I've been using the dummy app in the test folder for development and everything has worked as I expect.

If I package the engine up as a gem and install it into a separate rails app, when I try to access the engine in a browser I get the `Sprockets::FileNotFound` exception `couldn't find file`.

If I fire up the console and have a look at `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` it includes `mygem/app/assets` but not `mygem/vendor/assets`.

This is where it gets weird. If I change the rails app's Gemfile and load the engine directly from a path, I don't have these problems. I can view my engine in browser without any Sprockets issues. Loading up the console and looking at `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` shows both `path/to/mygem/app/assets` AND `path/to/mygem/vendor/assets`.

I don't get this. Why would I get different behaviour if the engine is being loaded as a packaged gem or directly from a path?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question. School-boy error, nothing to do with the asset pipeline, everything to do with adding the vendor path to the gemspec configuration.

```
s.files = Dir['{app,config,db,lib,vendor}/**/*', 'README.md', 'LICENSE.md']
```